# StreamBuilder don´t show data flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i have mi Streams in `bloc.dart`

```
class Bloc
{
  final _usuarioStream = StreamController<Usuario>.broadcast();
  
  Function(Usuario) get usuariosSink => _usuarioStream.sink.add;

  Stream<Usuario> get usuariosStream => _usuarioStream.stream;


  void disposeStream()
  {
    _usuarioStream?.close();
  }
}
```

So in my view `database.dart` i add data in my stream:

```
Bloc patron = new Bloc();
A lot of code..
patron.usuariosSink(usuarioact);
```

and in my last one view `HomePage.dart` i have a `StreamBuilder`

```
return StreamBuilder(
      stream:Bloc().usuariosStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot)
      {
         if(snapshot.hasError)
        {
          return Center(child: Text("Ocurrió un error"));
        }

        if(snapshot.hasData)
        {
          Usuario dato = snapshot.data;

          return Center(
      child:Text("${dato.nombre} ${dato.apellidos}",
      style:TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontFamily: "MPLUSRounded1c",
        fontSize: 18.0,
        ) ,
      ),
      );
          
        }
        else
        {
          return Center(child:Text("Error! no hay datos") ,);
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

i dont know what i wrong.

Comment: shouldn't the stream in StreamBuilder be patron.usuariosStream instead of Bloc().usuariosStream (don't create a new class, consume the one you created before)

Comment: i have them in separate files, but i will try as you explained

Comment: your stream's data is null because you aren't adding anything in the first place. Try watching some videos about streams and you'll figure out the problem :) Good Luck!